# package compiles with cabal but not with stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a short example using three functions from `hgeometry` which compiles with `cabal build`, but fails with `stack build`. It uses the same ghc version (8.10.7) installed with ghcup.

The error message from stack (LTS 18.28) and the code follow. I have the impression that the result types require a type paramter`s` which is not given in the input. But how is then `cabal build` satisfied? What am I missing?

```
/home/frank/Workspace11/StackGHC_hgeometry/app/TheMain.hs:54:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘PlanarSubdivision s p () () r’
                  with actual type ‘Triangulation p3 r2
                                    -> PlanarSubdivision r p3 () () r2’
    • Probable cause: ‘toPlanarSubdivision’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: toPlanarSubdivision t
      In an equation for ‘planarSubdiv2’:
          planarSubdiv2 t = toPlanarSubdivision t
    • Relevant bindings include
        t :: Triangulation p r (bound at app/TheMain.hs:54:15)
        planarSubdiv2 :: Triangulation p r -> PlanarSubdivision s p () () r
          (bound at app/TheMain.hs:54:1)
   |
54 | planarSubdiv2 t = toPlanarSubdivision t
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/home/frank/Workspace11/StackGHC_hgeometry/app/TheMain.hs:57:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘PlaneGraph s p () () r’
                  with actual type ‘Triangulation p2 r1 -> PlaneGraph r p2 () () r1’
    • Probable cause: ‘toPlaneGraph’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: toPlaneGraph t
      In an equation for ‘toPlaneGraph2’:
          toPlaneGraph2 t = toPlaneGraph t
    • Relevant bindings include
        t :: Triangulation p r (bound at app/TheMain.hs:57:15)
        toPlaneGraph2 :: Triangulation p r -> PlaneGraph s p () () r
          (bound at app/TheMain.hs:57:1)
   |
57 | toPlaneGraph2 t = toPlaneGraph t
```

The code is:

```
module Main     where      


import Data.Geometry.Point 
import qualified Data.Geometry.Point as HP
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NE 
import Data.PlaneGraph
import Data.Geometry.PlanarSubdivision
import Algorithms.Geometry.DelaunayTriangulation.Types
import Algorithms.Geometry.DelaunayTriangulation.Naive
import Data.Ext

fourPts = [(0,0,11), (1.5, 1.5, 12), (0,2,13), (2,0,14)] :: [(Double,Double,Int)]
to_HPoint (x,y,i) = HP.Point2 x y :+ i


main :: IO ()
main =  do  
    print "the input points"
    print . show $ fourHPoint
    let 
        del1 = delaunayTriangulation (NE.fromList fourHPoint) 
        planar1 = toPlanarSubdivision del1
        plane1 = toPlaneGraph del1
    print . show $ del1
    print . show $ planar1
    print . show $ plane1 


    return ()
```

The project can be copied from git@github.com:andrewufrank/StackGHC_hgeometry.git.

Hackage says for the two functions used:

```
toPlanarSubdivision :: proxy s -> Triangulation p r -> PlanarSubdivision s p () () r
```

and

```
toPlaneGraph :: forall proxy s p r. proxy s -> Triangulation p r -> PlaneGraph s Primal_ p () () r
```

Comment: You're probably using different versions of `hgeometry` in the two builds. I suggest you add a bound like `hgeometry >= 0.14 && < 0.15` to your `.cabal` file.

Comment: Indeed, this set of bounds results in a stack build with no problems. How did you come to the right conclusion? - I had assumed that stack would select the newest version (which is what the bounds now fix) and for the lts I have selected, stack used two older versions.  Thank you a lot for spotting it!

Comment: I wouldn't know an explanation for this compiler error, if the two builds were using the same set of dependencies. Since the compiler error refers to exports of `hgeometry`, it's easy to suspect that there's a difference in the versions of that package.

Comment: Note that even recent Stackage LTS snapshots frequently don't contain the latest package versions. The main reasons are that: 1. Within a given LTS series, only minor version bumps are done, e.g. v0.1.2 -> v0.1.3. 2. Stackage usually waits for downstream packages to catch up before performing any major version bumps.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the helpful reasoning what could cause such an error message. My hunch was completely off... It is difficult to decide whether to go with stack or cabal, none is perfect.

Comment: I usually recommend cabal these days. If you need reproducibility, give cabal`'s `index-state` option or cabal freeze files a try.

Comment: I read the cabal manual and will try to use `cabal freeze`. I learned something - thank you!